How to fix performance issue on kata containers + firecracker
I'm trying to run Kata containers with firecracker inside a VM I created on my proxmox cluster to test how kata containers work,
I used this guide to install the kata manager and this guide to make it work with firecraker, but the amount of resources that are being used is very high and i can't understand why.
I ran the following command
sudo ctr run --snapshotter devmapper --runtime io.containerd.run.kata-fc.v2 -t --rm docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest ubuntu_test
and the VM started using 32 GB of RAM and 100% of the CPU, making it impossible to send any other commands, I left it running and after 15 hours it stopped running for some reason.
I tried to list the containers available and it showed this

I tried multiple times to do the same thing and it always happens like shown bellow where it starts using an insane amount of RAM and CPU and it just stays there.

Other commands like removing a container or listing a container work fine, but for some reason when i try to run a container it always has this problem.
I feel like I have to be doing something wrong but I honestly have no idea what it could possibly be, any advice is appreciated. Also if it is actually supposed to be this heavy to run a confirmation of that would also be appreciated.
